# changing iframe src that include jquery cause memory leak only to ie ( ie8 and ie9 )

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, memory-leaks

i'm trying to deal with this one issue where my memory usage increment each time i change the src of my iframe. The src needs to be included with the jquery library in order for this problem to expose. I have been searching around and seems like jquery already knew this issue but they are not providing with any fix. I found other developers having similar issues while refreshing the page with jquery library. Unforturnately , there is no solutions to any of those issues yet. I am hoping there is someone here that knows how i can work around it as i 've been struggling with this for sometimes now.

Thanks in advance!!

Here is the code that will easily cause the probelm.

index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
                        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id='myform' action='tester.php'>
    <a href="" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('test').src = 'test.php';return false;" >click me</a>

    <iframe id="test" src="test.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" noresize="yes" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

test.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head> 
    <body style="height:100%" onload="">
    <div>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1> 
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you verified that it is indeed a leak and not just IE aggressively holding on to memory?  (I remember reading a while back that IE does not handle some freeing of DOM nodes correctly, but I think that was IE 6/7.  It could just be that IE is holding onto the memory for future use, especially if it's a small amount.)

Comment: yea..i tested it against Chrome and firefox and neither of them has the same issue. thanks!

Comment: But they may not have the same memory model as IE, meaning they may not aggressively hold onto memory (though I believe Firefox does... [kidding, just a jab at FF]).  A way to test it would be to see if it keeps growing past a certain point if you change the src over and over again.  Knowing IE, it probably really is a leak, but just not sure.  I'll try to find the article about IE leaks and see if it applies.